# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in C++ for pointer assignment

Tags: c++, string, pointers, memory, memory-management

I create a constant char variable `pStr` that is not zero terminated:

```
const unsigned char* pStr
```

I need to assign this to std::string

Currently I am using

```
std::string s((char *)(pStr));
```

I have also tried using

```
std::string s(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(pStr));
```

I am getting this error `"Segmentation fault (core dumped)"`

Appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please give a small program that demonstrates the crash.

Comment: The statements you show do effectively the same (more or less).

Comment: Why not `std::string s = pStr` or `std::string(pStr)`? Assuming `pStr` in zero terminated.

Comment: pStr is not zero terminated

Answer (score 2):

If the array that `pStr` points to is terminated according to the C convention with a zero-valued character, then your dodgy casts should work.

If it isn't, then you'll need some other way to determine the length of the string. Once you know that, you can initialise the string from its pointer range:

```
std::string s(pStr, pStr+length);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a correct expression

```
std::string s(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(pStr));
```

The reason of the dump is either the pointer is invalid for example it is equal to NULL or the string literal it points to does not have the terminating zero.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question I  have already tried with reinterpret_cast<const char *>(pStr) and the problem still persists

Answer (score -1):

```
Class A
{
  public : std::string myFunc( const unsigned char* a)
  {

   std::string s((char *)(a));

   return s;
  }
};
int main()
{
A sm;
cout<< sm.myFunc((const unsigned  char*)"abc");

}
```

Comment: In which way does this answer your question??

Comment: Sorry I should have edited in my question . Since I was asked to show piece of code I answered , instead of commenting which would look clumsy